# When would the private beta be ready for public beta?

Tags: discussion, beta-progress

Currently the site is in private beta, so all the questions/links are not accessible by non-users. The site already has over 240 questions and it'll pass 2 weeks soon.

When would the site be published and who decides it? What's still missing?

Related:

- [What criteria do we need to meet to ensure Vi and Vim continues beyond private beta?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/127/467)

Comment: Jon Ericson's approval, probably. And I suspect that it won't be a rubber-stamp process, based on [previous statements](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/a/149/24).

Comment: The other answers doesn't say when and what are the current blockers.

Comment: Seems the site is on now.

Comment: This question is off-topic now because this site has already entered public beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80441/vi-and-vim), the site appears to be in the "healthy" ranges for everything but traffic and user count.

I *think* those metrics are for the beta overall, not just the private portion thereof (because the user count metric is basically impossible to hit unless everybody invites a lot a people). However, they appear to be the most obvious measurable issues with the site right now.

---

Beyond those metrics, on a more subjective note, I would say that the most worrying aspect from my perspective is the large percentage of questions which seem to be either plugin recommendations or simply already on-topic at Stack Overflow, Super User, or another StackExchange site; these don't do enough to distinguish a dedicated vim site from others, especially given that that overlap has been the primary rationale for shutting down vim sites in proposal stage before.

We've had no official indication from StackExchange itself about the state of the site.

Comment: The Area 51 stats are mostly useless at the best of times and utterly irrelevant for this site. Private betas typically collect 100–200 questions, we have over 250, and voting is pretty high. The one thing that will make or break this site is whether it can prove its usefulness in addition to SO, SU and the other existing sites. In my opinion as a casual vi(m) user, quality is decent but not so significantly above SO that it justifies the site.