# How do we exit public beta (i.e., what are the criteria)?

Tags: discussion, beta-progress

Now we've made it into public beta (yay!), in a similar vein to [this question](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127/what-criteria-do-we-need-to-meet-to-ensure-vi-and-vim-continues-beyond-private-b?rq=1), what are the criteria (objective or subjective) we need to hit to have this site exit public beta and become a fully-fledged SE site?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/

Comment: There is no exit from the public beta. Once you join, you join for life. Leaving will have *severe* consequences for you and your family.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Joke's on you, doorknobs don't have families.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vi/Vim is a ways off from graduation, but looking forward — there are very few minimum criteria<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> for when a site becomes *eligible* for graduation, so the *actual* deciding factors are still largely subjective. We are generally looking for a robust site with a steady stream of high-quality quantity questions, enough to keep folks interested in the site on a sustained basis. We look at the turnover rate to see if the community has attracted an avid, core group of users. We look for an active and functional governance; i.e. does the community respond to and act on meta issues as they come up? Is their purpose and their scope pretty rock solid, or are there issues that still need to be resolved? We also look at the viability of holding a functional election (an intrinsic part of graduation). So generally speaking, we look for a site that has a sustained level of activity that all-but-guarantees the site can maintain a healthy pattern of growth for the foreseeable future.

But graduation doesn't happen on cue like a badge. We don't have a set goal that says *"if you do {x}, you will graduate."* We *are* getting there. We are honing in on those elusive "objective guidelines" that we'll (hopefully) be comfortable enough to publish and rely on exclusively — but we're not there yet. So graduation-checks come up periodically, and if everything looks good to go, we'll submit the site for their design.

I've written about this on several occasions; the posts below cover the crux of it:

- [When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)
- [Does this site have a chance of succeeding?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)
- [The New Stack Exchange Beta Theme](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup></sup><sub>Technically speaking, the "minimum requirements" for a site to become eligible are: >90 days (minimum) in public beta, 10+ users with 2,000 rep, and 5+ users with 3000 rep, although these numbers are rarely (read ***never***) the constraining factor.</sub>

Comment: Should contributors ask and answer their own questions to increase the quantity and quality of the questions on this site? For example taking an entry from vim.org's wiki and ask/answering the same concepts here?

Comment: @Sukima If you have another question, please post it using the 'ask question' feature. But the short answer is, no, don't start copying and answering question here in bulk as a way of increasing quality. The primary use case should be to ask about problems you actually have. See **[Asking the first questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)**.

Answer (score 3):

It happens "when it is ready".  When SE decides a critical mass of users and activity is sustained only then can a site graduate.

The stats on A51 are somewhat meaningless and the quoted "90 days" you'll see there is absolutely meaningless.  Look at other sites in beta and you'll find many that are multiple years old.  Expect to be in beta for a long time.

For a more detailed discussion and some examples, see: [Let's set better expectations for how long beta lasts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239464/lets-set-better-expectations-for-how-long-beta-lasts)