# Vi & Vim is graduating from Beta!

Tags: discussion, beta-progress

I am *very* excited to announce that yes, the Vi & Vim StackExchange will be
graduating from Beta. Look forward to the official name-change on December 16th,
2021 alongside other official meta posts from the SE community team.

### Upcoming changes

- Removal of Beta label
- Moderator election (sometime in 2022 or 2023, most likely)

### Things that won't change (yet)

- Site theme. SE is hoping to allow some customization in the future, but there
  is no timeline
- Reputation levels. The thresholds for privileges will not raise to their
  full-site counterparts, so nobody should lose any privileges when we graduate.
  We can revisit this in the future on Meta if and when the community has enough
  high-reputation users to sustain normal site curation.

### Love from your moderator team

We have all invested something special in this site. Having watched it grow from
a very tiny corner of the internet to a slightly less tiny corner of the
internet, we are very excited for the upcoming graduation. We know Vi & Vim has
faced some unique challenges, both as a StackExchange site and as an editor :P,
and we want to thank each and every one of you for contributing to make this
place what it is. Vi & Vim is consistently one of the most friendly and
welcoming communities we interact with, and you make it that way.

So give yourselves a pat on the back. You've earned it.

Comment: I've been trying to come up with some witty Vi-related answer/command, but I can't think of one :-( I can't believe it's been (almost) seven years since the beta started.

Comment: Congrats you all! It's so cool to see this great site finally graduating!

Comment: great news!   stackoverflow still gets a fair number of vi/vim questions daily, is there a plan to migrate more questions to vi.se now that it's out of beta?

Comment: @Mass I'm not sure. We'll need to get together with the SO community and ask if they want to revisit the scope of SO to exclude vi/vim so that new Qs can be moved here, or if they are happy with the status-quo.

Comment: Overview of # of Vi questions on different sites: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/611134/vi-questions-across-stack-exchange-per-month-with-graph#graph – just FYI. I hadn't looked at it in quite some time.

Comment: @MartinTournoij thanks; do we know if that includes neovim? I see `like %<vi>%` and `like %<vim>%` but it's not clear if `<>` are "word boundaries" there, probably bc I spend too much time with vim's patterns.

Comment: I'm not sure either @D.BenKnoble; Gilles wrote most of that query; I just modified it a bit (to add some sites, or the graph, or something; I forgot). I'm not very familiar with MS SQL Server's dialect of SQL, and [docs for like](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) don't mention `<` or `>`

Comment: Actually, I think it just stores/returns the tags as `<tag1> <tag2>`, and it's not special syntax at all; see e.g. [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1532864) (need to check "text only results". So to answer your question: yes, it only includes the Vim tag, and not "neovim". Not sure how many questions there are tagged only neovim.

Comment: @MartinTournoij added `[gvim]` and `[neovim]`. Does increase the counts some. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1532873/1876157/vi-questions-across-stack-exchange-per-month-with-graph#graph